# Command EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL do not create file in the server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

This command line runs smoothly in Win XP OS but when the OS was migrated to Win7. The command line does not create the file. This command line was set-up and runs in the server. What could be the check points in order to run this command line now that the OS is Win7?

Any help is appreciated.

```
DECLARE @c_cmd VARCHAR(100), 
              @ProgID VARCHAR(12)

SET @ProgID = 'INV'

SELECT @c_cmd = 'C:\MSSQL2000\INVIEW_LOCAL\PROC\INVIEW_INV_SETUP.bat' + @ProgID    
EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @c_CMD
```

Comment: check folder security first

Comment: If `@ProgID` is a parameter for `INVIEW_INV_SETUP.bat`, then aren't you missing space between them?

Comment: A constant value for @progid has been set.

Comment: @Alex, frikozoid said you should have spaces between your dir path and progID. Try adding space after .bat , secondly try running it manually by running cmd as administrator if it would work.

Comment: Already add a space after .bat and there is nothing happens when running the cmd manually. is there an alternative for xp_cmdshell method?